# SHA3 256 bit encryption

Tags: encryption

I am reading a research paper on image encryption using chaotic maps.and in between the paper they are using SHA3 encryption to produce 256 bits.
I am not able to understand how are they using SHA3 and how are the 32 hash values of the image being obtained.
please can somebody guide me on this.
some reference [image]

Comment: Right now this is impossible to answer, could you please link to said research paper?

Comment: http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11071-015-2465-7

Comment: In this case you have two options: Either include the relevant passages from the paper or contact the authors and ask them.

Comment: actually The link i have updated has that passage regarding SHA3

Comment: While the linked article may contain this passage many of us don't have a Springer Link subscription so we cannot access paywalled articles like this one.

Answer (score 1):

My guess: 256 bits = 32 bytes. So compute the SHA3-hash and use the decimal (in the example) values of the 32 resulting bytes.

Comment: how do i get the hash values can you tell

Comment: I suppose we compute the hash of the picture, it's just a file, so a sequence of bytes as well.